# assigning a nullable type to a non nullable variable

Tags: assemblyscript

I have the following statement:

```
  const to: Address = event.transaction.to;
```

the constant `to` must not be nullable for the rest of the logic but `event.transaction.to` is declared as `Address | null` and the compiler rightly complains that `Address | null is not assignable to type Address` (shortened message for readability)

I tried all the usual TypeScript tricks to assign the variable but nothing works. What is the correct way?

I tried this as suggested in the documentation:

```
  let to: Address = Address.fromString("0x0");
  if(event.transaction.to) {
    to = event.transaction.to;
  }
```

but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

the type has to be cast to a non nullable one:

```
if(event.transaction.to) {
   let to: Address = (event.transaction.to as Address)
...
}
```